# Probability of an "island" in a random map

Tags: probability

Given an n*n array of uniformly generated 1s and 0s, how would one find the probability that all of the 1s are touching (adjacent or diagonal), that there would be a "1 island"?

Comment: Your description is unclear. By “all of the ones are touching” you mean that you are interested in the probability of observing n*n ones and no zeros?

Comment: For reasonable values of $n$ simulation should be feasible but I am looking forward to more interesting answers. Not sure, if a maths forum might be a better place to ask.

Comment: If you just need numerical answers, I'd start with simulation. One thing you'll want to address is whether a grid with no 1's in it counts in the event or not (after all, there's no 1's isolated from any other 1's, so if you define it that way it counts)